# Typescript type from enum subsets

Tags: typescript, enums

i have enum:

```
export enum SampleEnum {
  ID = 'ID',
  PERSON = 'PERSON',
}
```

and the const:

```
export const SampleConst = {
  someValue1: [SampleEnum.PERSON, SampleEnum.ID].join('/'),
  someValue2: [SampleEnum.PERSON].join('/'),
}
```

How can i set a type of `SampleConst`  like `SampleEnum[].join('/')`?
Can I even do this?
Or maybe some regex types?

Id'd like to find some mapped type or generic type, that helps me. Maybe some post with advanced type-tricks. I already tried to get all subsets from enum, but its is'n good idea, i think

EDIT

I've tried to use this, to specify type of enum constant for routes in angular. For now, i have next:

```
enum ERoutesName {
  EMPTY = 'EMPTY',
  AUTH = 'AUTH',
  AUTH_PHONE = 'AUTH_PHONE',
  ...
}

export enum ERoutesParts {
  ID = ':id',
  EMPTY = '',
  AUTH = 'auth',
  AUTH_PHONE = 'auth-phone',
  ...
}

export const EPartialRoutes: <SomeSuperType>= {
  [ERoutesName.EMPTY]: [ERoutesParts.EMPTY].join('/'),
  [ERoutesName.AUTH]: [ERoutesParts.AUTH].join('/'),
  [ERoutesName.AUTH_PHONE]: [ERoutesParts.AUTH_PHONE].join('/'),
  ...
};
```

Comment: What did you intend to do with `[SampleEnum.PERSON].join('/')`?

Comment: There is no scalable specific type that represents an *arbitrary* concatenation of elements of a set of strings.  You can certainly write a type that captures the particular concatenations you're actually doing, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Wk3DLW).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining. If not, please [edit] to demonstrate a use case unsatisfied by this approach.

Comment: ... or, I suppose you could write a nominal-ish type that forces you to call a particular function to do the joining, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WvQqMm).  Please test both suggestions and let me know which, if either, meets your needs.

Comment: @jcalz, second variant is work for me, thank you so much!

Comment: @Behemoth use `SampleConst` as routes enum for angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no type `JoinedKeys<T>` that can accurately represent "any string formed by joining some subset of the keys of `T` with slashes.  As soon as `keyof T` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of eight or more members, the number of possible strings will be larger than the maximum size that can be held in an TypeScript union.  Even if this weren't the case, it would be asking the TypeScript compiler to keep track of the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) of acceptable values, and it doesn't look like you actually care about that.

Instead, I'd suggest making `JoinedKeys<T>` behave like a [nominal type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system), meaning it tries to represent where the value *came from* instead of (or in addition to) the actual structure of the value.  So we could have a function called `joinKeys(enum, ...keys)` that accepts an enum of type `T` and an array of keys of that enum. The return value of that function would be the expected joined string, but its *type*, `JoinedKeys<T>`, is a `string` that has been "branded" so that the compiler knows it is the result of calling `joinKeys(enum, ...keys)`.  See [the FAQ entry for how to make a type behave nominally](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal)

Like this:

```
type JoinedKeys<T extends Record<keyof T, string>> =
    string & { __joinedFrom: T };
function joinKeys<T extends Record<keyof T, string>>(enm: T, ...indices: readonly (keyof T)[]) {
    return indices.map(k => enm[k]).join("/") as JoinedKeys<T>;
}
```

So now you can say that `SampleConst` is of type `{[k: string]: JoinedKeys<typeof SampleEnum>}`:

```
const SampleConst: { [k: string]: JoinedKeys<typeof SampleEnum> } = {
    someValue1: joinKeys(SampleEnum, "PERSON", "ID"),
    someValue2: joinKeys(SampleEnum, "PERSON")
}; // okay
```

The compiler will only allow you to add properties whose value is of type `JoinedKeys<typeof SampleEnum>`, and the only reasonable way to obtain one of those is to call `joinKeys(SampleEnum, ...keys)`:

```
enum OtherEnum {
    X = 'OOPS'
}

const BadSampleConst: { [k: string]: JoinedKeys<typeof SampleEnum> } = {
    oops0: "random string", // error
    oops1: "PERSON/ID", // error
    okay: joinKeys(SampleEnum, "PERSON", "ID"), // okay
    oops2: joinKeys(OtherEnum, "X"), // error
}
```

Random strings are rejected.  So are valid strings which did not come from `joinKeys()`, but that's just the way this works; we're not asking the compiler to care about the literal value of the string, just where it came from.  And so are strings which came from calling `joinKeys()` with a different, incompatible enum.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAyghhADgG2AUXNA3gKCvqASQBEoBeKAchMoBo8CAFNAJRgHkA5cq5trujgC+OHABcAnomBQAUgHsAliGAATANLAJAZwA8AFSjAAHmNCrtUFsADG8gE6rdAay3yAZlH20o2sfeUAcwA+YPIGfD8AkECoADIoLCgAfWSAKyUVVQAxe3kIAC4vKCEAbhx3MBAbMUV5ECgM5U0dAyNTc0trO0cXN09vX38g0IAKUEKvHwA6WeVVRRtgbSL7YDhVeuQJKFHXCQ8vAEoAbQBdI8SIqDWxMHsG+cXl6Yg4RD3yMImT5wvppogUYAIgA9MDLnBLAplGoWnp9MFyiIcHYQH5YAgUMAAML1PxFJK-IpRIJnIowrLw3SSaSHeBIVAYSBhIQ8XAEXz5YAANTgyDAwAAjEVAfDRgzscyID5gXwOJxgbKSBD6JztNy+QLgAAmUWZcWSpmYWXyrgQ4SiUCQKDsMQAC2A9mlV05AA0eJR2OxGDBKJbUfixFAAEIbI24oOEqDEobRQLkuSZOFaPS04D0rHGlkldnXeTyRDaAAMRWB9jgIE20FJMSVUFBoKM9jy9nzhe0IqgctYCtBKp8jebrfzzjgEn1zVTEqz6BN3bNiuVxFVDab8jHEnbRb1jQN07tjud8+BbtXQ6dI6EQA)